# Неправильно работает TextBox в WPF. Ввод происходит только при нажатии на границу TexBox'а, а нужно как обычно: нажатие на поле ввода

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<!--Стиль для элементов TextBox-->
  <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextColor1}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding TextBox.Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding TextBox.BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="11"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding TextBox.Text}" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Palatino Linotype"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource IsMouseOverColor}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource IsMouseOverColor}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Сверху код стиля TextBox'а. В нём я переопределяю шаблон и добавляю туда же триггеры. Всё работает как и должно, но если обычный TextBox позволяет вводить текст при нажатии на ПОЛЕ ввода, то мой TextBox становится "активным" только при нажатии на его ГРАНИЦЫ(поэтому толстыми сделала их). Что нужно добавить в шаблон, чтобы в TextBox можно ввести текст при наводке на поле для ввода?

Comment: `{x:Null}` -> `Transparent`

Comment: Спасибо, теперь работает)